# Shadcn Dialog inside of Dropdown closes automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I use shadcn in my next.js 13 project. I want to have a dropdown with the option to edit or delete an entry. When the user clicks on "delete" a dialog should pop up and ask them for a confirmation. However, the dialog only shows for about 0.5 seconds before it closes together with the dropdown. How can I prevent that from happening?

Here is the example on codesandbox: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/shadcn-playground-3gs3v6?file=%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Futils.js%3A1%2C1)

This is the code:

```html
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <p>Trigger</p>
      </DropdownMenuTrigger>
      <DropdownMenuContent>
        <Dialog>
          <DropdownMenuLabel>Edit Entry</DropdownMenuLabel>
          <DropdownMenuSeparator />
          <DropdownMenuItem
            onClick={() => conosle.log("Navigate to edit page")}
          >
            Edit
          </DropdownMenuItem>
          <DialogTrigger>
            <DropdownMenuItem>Delete</DropdownMenuItem>
          </DialogTrigger>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogHeader>
              <DialogTitle>Are you sure?</DialogTitle>
              <DialogDescription>
                Do you want to delete the entry? Deleting this entry cannot be
                undone.
              </DialogDescription>
            </DialogHeader>
            <DialogFooter>
              <DialogClose asChild>
                <Button variant="outline">Cancel</Button>
              </DialogClose>
              <Button>Delete</Button>
            </DialogFooter>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </DropdownMenuContent>
    </DropdownMenu>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### What is the problem?

When you click any `<DropdownMenuItem />`, It will trigger the action (onClick) and close (unmount) the `<DropdownMenuContent />` which includes the `<DialogContent />` so it'll be unmounted with it.

### Solutions

#### 1. Move the `<DialogContent />` outside of the `<DropdownMenuContent />`

```
// ...
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Dialog> {/*  The dialog provider outside of the DropdownMenuContent */}
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <p>Trigger</p>
        </DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <DropdownMenuContent>
          <DropdownMenuItem>
            <DialogTrigger>
              Open Popup
            </DialogTrigger>
          </DropdownMenuItem>
        </DropdownMenuContent>
      </DropdownMenu>
      {/*  DialogContent ouside of DropdownMenuContent */}
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Are you sure?</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            Do you want to delete the entry? Deleting this entry cannot be
            undone.
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <DialogFooter>
          <DialogClose asChild>
            <Button variant="outline">Cancel</Button>
          </DialogClose>
          <Button>Delete</Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

This solution works well if you have a single item triggers dialog. But what if you have multiple dialogs?

#### 2. Multiple dialogs

Move your dialog outside the `<DropdownMenuContent />`, create a state for each one:

```
const [isEditDialogOpen, setIsEditDialogOpen] = useState(false)
const [isDeleteDialogOpen, setIsDeleteDialogOpen] = useState(false)
```

then remove any `<DialogTrigger />`, add onClick instead

```
<DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => setIsEditDialogOpen(true)}>Edit</DropdownMenuItem>
<DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => setIsDeleteDialogOpen(true)}>Delete</DropdownMenuItem>
```

In your dialog add

```
<Dialog open={isEditDialogOpen || isDeleteDialogOpen} 
        onOpenChange={isEditDialogOpen ? 
            setIsEditDialogOpen : setIsDeleteDialogOpen}>
...
</Dialog>
```

If you don't want to make it controlled and can render two trigger buttons, you can render two separate dialogs:

```js
<Dialog>
  <DialogTrigger>Edit Post</DialogTrigger>
  <DialogContent>
     Content 
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>

<Dialog>
  <DialogTrigger>Edit Post</DialogTrigger>
  <DialogContent>
    Content 
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problems.

Comment: Great answer Ahmed! You helped me out on the multiple dialogs part. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default behavior of the `onClick` event which I believe is renamed to `onSelect` (https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/dropdown-menu) on `DropdownMenuItem`.

This way you can extract `Dialog` logic into a separate component and simply include it inside your `Dropdown` wrapper:

```
// {...}
<DropdownMenu>
  <DropdownMenuTrigger>
    <p>Trigger</p>
  </DropdownMenuTrigger>
  <DropdownMenuContent>
    <DropdownMenuLabel>Edit Entry</DropdownMenuLabel>
    <DropdownMenuSeparator />
    <DropdownMenuItem onSelect={() => console.log("Navigate to edit page")}>
      Edit
    </DropdownMenuItem>
    <DropdownMenuItem onSelect={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      <YourCustomDialog />
    </DropdownMenuItem>
  </DropdownMenuContent>
</DropdownMenu>;
// {...}

const YourCustomDialog = () => {
  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogTrigger>Delete</DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Are you sure?</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            Do you want to delete the entry? Deleting this entry cannot be
            undone.
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <DialogFooter>
          <DialogClose asChild>
            <Button variant="outline">Cancel</Button>
          </DialogClose>
          <Button>Delete</Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

The drawback of this implementation is that the dropdown menu stays open while you interact with `Dialog`, though you can reuse `YourCustomDialog` component.